# Error ProgressDialog junto con hilos en Android

Tags: android, hilos, diálogo

Tengo la siguiente estructura en mi clase:

```
public class Registro extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);
    enviar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.enviarDatos);

    enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    enviarDatos();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });

private void enviarDatos() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Registro.this, "Registrando", "Espere, por favor...");

    final Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ...codigo...
        }
    });

    final Thread pb=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog=null;
            ...codigo...
        }
    }):
}
}
```

El problema que tengo es que me da error en la linea de creación del ProgressDialog, "...has leaked window", todo el rato.

Pongo simplemente la estructura de la clase porque en otra que tengo idéntica, me lo hace bien, la única diferencia es que en la otra, llamo a `enviarDatos()` directamente desde el `onCreate()` directamente (sin listener ni clase anónima ni nada) y así no me da problemas.

Si el problema reside en esto último comentado, ¿qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?. En caso contrario, ¿cuál es la causa probable para que me de dicho error?

Answer (score 2):

Este error surge cuando la `Activity` que inicio el `ProgressDialog`, no existe, esta en pausa o fue destruida.

Como solución para evitar este problema, define una variable para determinar cuando al `Activity` que crea el `ProgressDialog` es visible

```
private static boolean foreground = true; //valida si permite mostrar el ProgressDialog.
```

e implementa los siguientes métodos:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    foreground = false;
  super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    foreground = true;
  super.onResume();
}
```

y valides de esta forma si se muestra o no el `ProgressDialog`, para evitar el error `has leaked window`:

```
  if(foreground){
       progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Registro.this, "Registrando", "Espere, por favor...");
   }
```